# Resize image to exact size by maintaining aspect ratio nodejs

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, image-resizing, gm

I want to resize image to an exact size by maintaining aspect ratio and filling the empty space with transparency using nodejs.

I am able to do it using canvas. But due to some server os issues I can not use canvas.

I tried with imageMagick and gm. But couldn't find any option like these. Please show me a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can resize and fill to the exact size by

```
convert image -resize WxH -background none -gravity center -extent WxH output
```

Input:

[image]

Here I will make the background black so you can see that if fills it out.

```
convert lena.jpg -resize 400x300 -background black -gravity center -extent 400x300 lena1.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Change the background color, if you want, say white, in place of the black fill.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have been successful using the canvas for resizing images, you can check out https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas this repo.

As already mentioned you also resize images using ImageMagick by processes in NodeJS ( http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/ )

```
convert dragon.gif  -resize 64x64  resize_dragon.gif
```

In case you have a lot of images, I would suggest that you write a terminal script ( NodeJS can achieve that as well ).

I hope it helps, in case you have more queries, feel free to ask.